# Retrieve Order in Observer

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, magento-1, sales-order

I have created an observer that hooks into the `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_view` event. In this observer I want to set the order's `hasForcedCanCreditmemo` to `TRUE`.

I am unsure how to retrieve the order, though - I can't see anywhere that the order ID is being passed through.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I would get the order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your observer class you can do the following:

```
public function changeOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $orderId = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
}
```

Thus, you will have your order available in the `$order` variable.